# What would it mean if a circuit board all of a sudden works after it doesn’t work for some time?

Tags: short-circuit, hardware, debugging

Sorry for my noob question. I am very new to debugging hardware circuit boards.

A circuit board was not working. After measuring a voltage rail it was jumping from 12V to 0V, and back to 12, etc. what kind of behavior does this typically indicate?

The board randomly worked by not doing anything besides probing a few areas with a multimeter (it wasn’t working for a few days). How is that possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It could be an intermittent connection of some kind, something like a bad solder joint or a hairline crack in the board or a lifted pad on a single-side PCB. You can troubleshoot many of that kind of fault with copious quantities of light and close visual inspection at various angles.

Of course if it got wet, then there are other possibilities. If you know what the history of the intermittent board is you have a better chance of being able to fix it.

Cold solder joints may work for a while after being disturbed until corrosion once again pays them a visit and they cease working. Hence the occasional success of "percussive maintenance" (giving the device a whack).

The general rule is that things that suddenly start to work will suddenly stop again at some later (and often inconvenient) date.

As @mkeith suggests, thermal shutdown can play a role (perhaps a regulator is overloaded or a cooling fan has failed so an IC goes into protection mode and then recovers once the die temperature drops sufficiently).

Open circuits in particular can be affected by temperature. Sometimes there  is a fault inside an IC package or other component that will come and go with temperature changes.

Some CMOS circuits can undergo non-destructive latch-up where they stop working until the power has been cycled following some kind of probing or short. More modern designs are usually pretty resistant to that mode of failure, at least from external-to-PCB sources, and  usually have enough power supply current to fry the latched-up chip dead, should it ever occur, so that's less common soft failure these days.

Crummy cheap reset circuits and lack of proper watchdog timer strategies can cause microcontrollers to appear to fail upon partial power cycling or some kind of upset (lightning, probing, cosmic rays, firmware memory leak or timing-related issue), only to start working again upon a full power cycle.

Comment: Maybe thermal cycling too, if the 12 V regulator was overheating and shutting down. I don't want to write a whole answer myself because you already basically answered it. If you feel it is worthwhile maybe you can just add that to your answer as an additional possibility.

Comment: And a "hiccuping" DC-DC converter will cause voltage oscillations (0-12V).  Perhaps the DC-DC was hiccuping because some connection was shorted, and moving the board while testing un-shorted it.  Could have even been a small piece of metal stuck to the board.  Use eyes very closely (or get someone with really good eyesight to help.)

Answer (score 2):

Others had excellent suggestions. When we see odd behavior in circuit boards the first thing we try is to clean the board in isopropyl alcohol using an ultrasonic cleaner. Flux between high impedance pins will often cause stray currents that can pull pins low that should be high. It doesn't cost much (other than time) and sometimes fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While the already mentioned mechanical problems are a *much* more probable cause for this behavior, it is also possible to be caused by electrical side effects of the measuring attempts. Even the high impedance of a voltage measurement *can* be enough to switch a mosfet, and resistance measuring or diode testing functions are *definitely* able to. Such a charged gate can stay so for considerable time and throw off subsequent measurements of related parts in the circuit.